# Estou com duvida em como inserir varios elementos dentro do banco pelo mysql.connector

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

```
import mysql.connector

mysql.connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                                          user='root',
                                          password='rgs050601',
                                          database='testegr')

sql = "INSERT INTO pet (id,numero,idade) VALUES %s"

pd = "(5,6,1),(9,8,1),(7,5,9)"

cursor = mysql.connection.cursor()

cursor.execute(sql,(pd,))
mysql.connection.commit()
```

esse não é meu codigo original so fiz como base de teste bem simples
queria inserir os valores de pd direto na query mas sem usar o executemany ou concatenar os valores na string de cima que seria a da pesquisa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma maneira de resolver, utilizando o seu código é utilizando o modelo de `f-string` do python 3. Para isso basta modificar o seu código para:

```
import mysql.connector

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                              user='root',
                              password='rgs050601',
                              database='testegr')

sql = "INSERT INTO pet (id,numero,idade) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)"
pd = [(5,6,1),(9,8,1),(7,5,9)]

cursor = cnx.cursor()

for item in pd:
    print(item) #esta linha é desnecessária e pode ser removida
    cursor.execute(sql, item)
cnx.commit()
```

Verifique que para isso foi necessário mudar a variável `sql`.

Também foi necessário modificar a variável `pd`.

Para poder inserir várias linhas foi necessário colocar para inserir linha a linha em um laço for.
Para mais informações é possível ver na documentação [mais detalhes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-cursor-transaction.html).

Caso você queira é possível utilizar a sua abordagem, porém é necessário deixar de utilizar o `f-string` e usar o método `format` do string.

Observe que no final da string existe um `{}` é naquele espaço que vamos concatenar a string que desejamos.

Segue um exemplo:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO pet (id,numero,idade) VALUES {}"
pd = '(5,6,1),(9,8,1),(7,5,9)'
cursor = cnx.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql.format(pd))
cnx.commit()
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, o primeiro metodo acho que seria inviável pra mim, mas a segunda com format eu n tinha pensado ainda pode ser que de certo , n sabia que podia trabalhar com o format dentro da dos parametros ali, mas ajudou mto